# A fair die is rolled $5$ times and the outcomes are listed. The probability that the list contains exactly $3$ different numbers is

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> A fair die is rolled $5$ times and the outcomes are listed. The probability that the list contains exactly $3$ different numbers is

**My attempt**
There are $6^5$  outcomes.  Now as there are only $3$ numbers, there are $^6C_3$ choices and $125$ ways of choosing these by the fundamental principal of counting, thus, the probability is $~0.074$, however, my book says it's $0.38$. Why isn't my answer correct?

$$P=\frac{{125 \cdot~^6C_3}}{6^5}$$

Comment: Did you mean to ask why your answer is incorrect?

Comment: yes, I posted it without finsing my question by mistake

Comment: I posted an answer in which I explained how to solve the problem, which may show you what you were doing wrong.  However, it is not clear to me how you obtained $125$, so I cannot give you a precise explanation of what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks f the answers and help everyone, If it's fine I'll accept an answer within 24 hours

Answer (score 3):

Your denominator is correct.  In the numerator, you have to choose which numbers appear, how many times they appear, and in which positions they appear.  You chose which numbers appear, but it is not clear how you tried to account for the latter two steps.

There are two possibilities:

- One number appears three times, while two other numbers each appear once.
- Two numbers each appear twice, while another number appears once.

*One number appears three times, while two other numbers each appear once*:  There are six ways to select the number which appears three times, $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select three of the five positions for that number, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select which two of the remaining five numbers each appear once, and $2!$ ways to arrange those numbers in the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}2!$$
such outcomes.

*Two numbers each appear twice, while another number appears once*:  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select which two of the six numbers will each appear twice, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two of the five positions for the larger of those numbers, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select two of the remaining three positions for the smaller of those numbers, and $4$ ways to select the number that appears once, which must fill the remaining position.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$
such outcomes.

*Number of favorable cases*:  Since the two cases above are exhaustive and mutually exclusive, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}2! + \binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}$$

Hence, the probability that exactly three different numbers appear in five rolls of a fair die is
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{5}{2}2! + \dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}}{6^5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Expressing the probability as

$$\frac{N}{D},$$

where $D = 6^5$, you have to identify each possible way of partitioning the number $(5)$ into $3$ different numbers.  The partitions will **not** be equally likely.  So, unless someone has an alternative approach, I will forgo any attempt at elegance, take off my shoes and count.

- The largest number possible is $3$, which yields to the sequence $3-1-1$.  This sequence represents that there are $3$ of one number and $1$ each of two other numbers.
  There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{2} = 60$ choices for which of the 6 possible elements in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ will occur $(3)$ times, and then which of the other two elements will occur one time each. 
  There is a $\color{red}{\text{subtle trap here}}.$ 
  In such a probability problem, the numerator and denominator must be computed in a consistent manner.
  The $6^5$ computation of the denominator indicates that when computing the denominator, the **order** that the numbers are rolled are considered distinct. For example, rolling $1-1-1-2-3$ is considered distinct from rolling $2-3-1-1-1.$ 
  Therefore, in the $3-1-1$ sequence, when enumerating the numerator, you must include the additional factor of $(5 \times 4 = 20)$, which signifies that there are $(5)$ choices for which position the first singleton number will occur in, and then $(4)$ choices for which position the 2nd singleton number will occur in.  
  So, the enumeration for the 3-1-1 sequence is 
  $60 \times 20 = 1200.$
- The only other possible sequence, which results in $3$ distinct numbers in $(5)$ rolls is $2-2-1.$ 
  There are
  $\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}$ ways of selecting the two numbers what will each occur twice, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}$ way of selecting which other number will be the singleton.  
  Then, the singleton has $\displaystyle\binom{5}{1}$ choices for which of the $5$ rolls it occurs in.  Then, there are $\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}$ ways of distributing the other two pairs, among the $(4)$ **remaining** rolls. 
  So, the enumeration here is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} = 1800$.

---

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{1200 + 1800}{6^5}.$$

Comment: why exactly is the largest possible number 3?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Since you are only rolling $5$ dice, and since you are specifically interested in having **three** distinct numbers, you can not have **four** of the **five** dice all showing the same number.  If that were to occur, you would not be able to have the **five** dice simultaneously showing **three** distinct numbers.  However, if instead, **three** of the **five** dice all show the same number, then you can have each of the two remaining dice showing different numbers.   ...see next comment

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Actually, your posted problem calls for rolling only a single die, **five** times.  However, this analogizes to rolling **five** different dice, once each.  Also, my answer is **not worded very clearly**.  "...the largest possible number is $(3)$..." : I intend that to mean that with the five dice, you can have as many as three of the dice showing the same number, but you can not have four of the dice showing the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Case $1$:

Number of ways choosing exactly $3$ different numbers out of $6$ is $\binom{6}{3}$

Number of ways choosing $1$ of these $3$ numbers is $\binom{3}{1}$

Number of different arrangmets is $\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{1}\times \frac{5!}{3!\times 1! \times 1!}$

Case $2$:

Number of ways choosing exactly $3$ different numbers out of $6$ is $\binom{6}{3}$

Number of ways choosing $2$ of these $3$ numbers is $\binom{3}{2}$

Number of different arrangmets is $\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{2}\times \frac{5!}{2!\times 2!}$

From case $1\&2$, the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{1}\times \frac{5!}{3!\times 1! \times 1!} +\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{2}\times \frac{5!}{2!\times 2!}}{6^5}$$